# How to create splitted in sections input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to create phone input where each number placed in individual input. At least I thinking that way.

[image]

I already created inputs and connected them to one array. 
Data: `const value = ['', '', '', ... ]`. 
But the problem with it that I should somehow switch from input to input every character input or on remove characters.

How better to create input like that?

I had created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/amazing-night-582h3) with React.

Comment: what about to create a masked input, with a invisible background color and fixed font, and then a fixed mask in the under layer?

Comment: This library brings a solution to this problem in case you want to use it [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#format-phone-number)

Comment: @JoaoPolo I think it will hard to match symbols (like `(` or `–`) in mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can save the refs of each input and call focus on change value. Here is done for adding and removing values.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]);
  const [ref] = useState([null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]);

  const onChangeValue = (newValue, index) => {
    if (newValue.match(/(\d|^(?![\s\S]))/g) && newValue.length <= 2) {
      setValue([
        ...value.slice(0, index),
        newValue.slice(-1),
        ...value.slice(index + 1)
      ]);
      if (newValue.length > 0 && ref[index + 1]) {
        ref[index + 1].focus();
      }
    }
  };

  const onRemove = (key, index) => {
    if (key === "Backspace") {
      ref[index - 1].focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>(</span>
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[0] = input;
        }}
        value={value[0]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 0)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[1] = input;
        }}
        value={value[1]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 1)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 1)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[2] = input;
        }}
        value={value[2]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 2)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 2)}
      />
      <span>)</span>
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[3] = input;
        }}
        value={value[3]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 3)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 3)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[4] = input;
        }}
        value={value[4]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 4)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 4)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[5] = input;
        }}
        value={value[5]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 5)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 5)}
      />
      <span>–</span>
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[6] = input;
        }}
        value={value[6]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 6)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 6)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[7] = input;
        }}
        value={value[7]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 7)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 7)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[8] = input;
        }}
        value={value[8]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 8)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 8)}
      />
      <input
        ref={input => {
          ref[9] = input;
        }}
        value={value[9]}
        onChange={({ target }) => onChangeValue(target.value, 9)}
        onKeyUp={({ key }) => onRemove(key, 9)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-breeze-q4pez)

Comment: I was updating it Andy, new to answering so was finding it difficult to edit